# How to detect irregular objects in a binary image?

Tags: python, image-processing, imagej

I have binary microscopy images of fibers which are embedded inside a polymer matrix and I need to segment the image into fiber and matrix in order to get the fiber content.

[image]

I tried fill_holes, but it doesn’t get all the fibers.

After fill_holes:

[image]Do you have any solutions here?
The original microscopy image (prior to binarization) is here:

As I mentioned, the goal is to segment this image into fiber and background (polymer matrix material)

[image]

Comment: didn't work because either are not closed objects (you can see they are open by few pixels) or touch the border of the image (and therefore are not close objects). try to apply some morphology operators on the image so you can make those object closed ones. Take a look [HERE](https://imagej.net/plugins/morphological-segmentation) and [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology)

Comment: Do the following: Make a 1 or 2 pixel border around the image, so objects touching the borders will automatically be closed. Then you want to apply a "closing" morphological operator to close the objects. You can also apply some eroding to eliminate small dust points. look at https://canvas.colorado.edu/courses/61439/pages/morphological-opening-and-closing?module_item_id=2009591#:~:text=Morphological%20closing%20is%20a%20dilation,close%20gaps%20in%20the%20image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.